# scanning from file to generate binary tree

Tags: c, file, binary-tree, permutation

I am writing a program to generate permutation of a given series of numbers like
10,11,12,32,33,45,56,67
then output (which is all permutation of this series) I am storing in a file result.txt 
I have to generate a binary tree from each line of input in result.txt

I know the program to create a binary tree when a user gives numbers as input but here I am having a file as an example I had initially given input as 9  numbers 87,80,65,45,32,22,109,9,6 I am storing in result.txt as follows.

```
87 80 65 45 32 22 109 9 6
87 65 80 45 32 22 109 9 6
87 65 45 80 32 22 109 9 6
87 65 45 32 80 22 109 9 6
87 65 45 32 22 80 109 9 6
87 65 45 32 22 109 80 9 6
87 65 45 32 22 109 9 80 6
87 65 45 32 22 109 9 6 80
65 87 45 32 22 109 9 6 80
65 45 87 32 22 109 9 6 80
65 45 32 87 22 109 9 6 80
65 45 32 22 87 109 9 6 80
65 45 32 22 109 87 9 6 80
65 45 32 22 109 9 87 6 80
65 45 32 22 109 9 6 87 80
65 45 32 22 109 9 6 80 87
45 65 32 22 109 9 6 80 87
45 32 65 22 109 9 6 80 87
45 32 22 65 109 9 6 80 87
45 32 22 109 65 9 6 80 87
45 32 22 109 9 65 6 80 87
45 32 22 109 9 6 65 80 87
45 32 22 109 9 6 80 65 87
45 32 22 109 9 6 80 87 65
32 45 22 109 9 6 80 87 65
32 22 45 109 9 6 80 87 65
32 22 109 45 9 6 80 87 65
32 22 109 9 45 6 80 87 65
32 22 109 9 6 45 80 87 65
32 22 109 9 6 80 45 87 65
32 22 109 9 6 80 87 45 65
32 22 109 9 6 80 87 65 45
22 32 109 9 6 80 87 65 45
22 109 32 9 6 80 87 65 45
22 109 9 32 6 80 87 65 45
22 109 9 6 32 80 87 65 45
22 109 9 6 80 32 87 65 45
22 109 9 6 80 87 32 65 45
22 109 9 6 80 87 65 32 45
22 109 9 6 80 87 65 45 32
109 22 9 6 80 87 65 45 32
109 9 22 6 80 87 65 45 32
109 9 6 22 80 87 65 45 32
109 9 6 80 22 87 65 45 32
109 9 6 80 87 22 65 45 32
109 9 6 80 87 65 22 45 32
109 9 6 80 87 65 45 22 32
109 9 6 80 87 65 45 32 22
9 109 6 80 87 65 45 32 22
9 6 109 80 87 65 45 32 22
9 6 80 109 87 65 45 32 22
9 6 80 87 109 65 45 32 22
9 6 80 87 65 109 45 32 22
9 6 80 87 65 45 109 32 22
9 6 80 87 65 45 32 109 22
9 6 80 87 65 45 32 22 109
6 9 80 87 65 45 32 22 109
6 80 9 87 65 45 32 22 109
6 80 87 9 65 45 32 22 109
6 80 87 65 9 45 32 22 109
6 80 87 65 45 9 32 22 109
6 80 87 65 45 32 9 22 109
6 80 87 65 45 32 22 9 109
6 80 87 65 45 32 22 109 9
80 6 87 65 45 32 22 109 9
80 87 6 65 45 32 22 109 9
80 87 65 6 45 32 22 109 9
80 87 65 45 6 32 22 109 9
80 87 65 45 32 6 22 109 9
80 87 65 45 32 22 6 109 9
80 87 65 45 32 22 109 6 9
80 87 65 45 32 22 109 9 6
```

now the problem is if I use a function like fgets()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
        FILE *fp;
        char line[60];
        fp=fopen("result.txt","r");
        while (fgets(line,60,fp)){
        puts(line);
        }
        fclose(fp);

}
```

I just want the array elements to come separately in different array elemnents with output of puts or fgets this is what I am not able to think of,
any idea of doing this as how to approach this to solve is welcome.  Since I do not knew how to store the output of permutation generation in array so I thought of storing output in a file. Upto here program is fine but after this how do I read each integer of series from line in result.txt is my problem I am not able to think of any C implemented function as to do so.

Comment: If you successfully managed to load a line with `fgets()`, why not making a loop with [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read number for number from read string and storing it in your tree until `sscanf()` fails due to end of string?

Comment: i m not aware of such functions i was instead thinking to do a fork() to generate tree

Comment: Are you aware the [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) is responsible to make child processes? You may or may not create a tree of child processes for this (though I didn't read your question in that way) but you still have to parse the string filled with `fgets()` to get out the numbers. For the latter, I recommend `sscanf()` but, of course, you can do it "manually" as well by evaluating each single char for this and converting consecutive digits to `int` by addition and multiplication. (This is another frequent Q/A you will find in SO.)

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to do. Shall each line in the file generate a binary tree so that you end with 72 binary trees each containing 9 elements?

Comment: @4386427 yes you got it correct this is a home work problem deadline for which is already over there will be 72 trees for each line .

Comment: @ss321c Seems your next step is to parse the `line` and extract the numbers in it. See the example code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463973/4386427 Maybe that will help.

Comment: @ss321c Quote: "Since I do not knew how to store the output of permutation generation in array" Hmm... maybe you should really have asked about that instead. If you don't actually need the file, it seems very strange to write to a file and the read it back in....

Comment: @4386427 yes I had asked about that in different words and the result is question was downvoted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495226/using-output-of-a-program-as-input-in-same-program you may look at code in my answer which is generating the permuation list ,this will be used as input in subsequent calls from file result.txt and since I don't understand how to proceed further ,I stored the result in file

Comment: some one has implemented a similar thing https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/total-number-of-possible-binary-search-trees-with-n-keys/ but my question and problem both are different, I am doing for n permutations